# React Native: How to add Google Play service when login with Google+ for Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm a newbie in React Native. I'm researching about Login with Google+ on Android device.

I'm using `react-native-google-signin` package.

When i launch app on simulator it says "Google Play services is not supported by your device.Contact the manufacturer for assistance"

And `react-native-google-signin` package requires install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer). In my Android SDK manager says "Not compatible with Mac OS".Its revision is 6.0.5.

[HAXM 6.0.5 in Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAzUA.png)

But in Android Studio, its revision is 6.0.3.

[HAXM 6.0.3 in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBboH.png)

How to upgrade HAXM from 6.0.3 to 6.0.5?
Please help me to fix it. I'm using Mac OSX 10.11.6 El Capitan.

Thank you!